# How can I delete text before a pattern (--------------) in Linux

Tags: shell, text-processing

There is one file in which I am getting data after a pattern 
`--------------` (14 dashes). I want to generate the file in which I will get the text after 14 dashes.

Filename is `portals.csv` and
Text in the file is like:

```
xyz 
anch 
skjbsejkbkjsbj 
183y83yy3e 
29292.2982 282823 
CSV File begin 
-------------- 
ip,time,release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want everything after the line of dashes, not just one line:

```
$ sed -E '0,/^-{14}/d' portals.csv 
ip,time,release
some,more,data
```

`0,/-{14}/` matches from the beginning of file (`0`), to the first line that starts with fourteen dashes. `d` deletes the matched lines. `-E` tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions, the alternative would be `/^-\{14\}/`. (This would also match lines with more than fourteen dashes, or any trailing garbage after them.)

Using `0` as the start of the range is a GNU extension. With a standard sed, something like this:

```
< portals.csv sed -nE  -e '/^-{14}/,$p' | sed 1d
```

(`sed -E '1,/^-{14}/d'`, would fail if the line of dashes is the first line of the file.)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks it worked. You are awesome :) You made my day

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -0pe 's/^.*-{14}//g' portals.csv  > portals_clean.csv
```

Or if you are using whole lines you can use grep

```
grep -A 1 -P "-{14}" portals.csv  | tail -n 1 > portals_clean.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, It's saying command not found. Please correct me, I am executing the command as below:
 portals.csv perl -0pe 's/^.*-{14}//g' > test.csv
-bash: portals.csv: command not found

File name is portals.csv and text in file is like:
xyz anch
skjbsejkbkjsbj
183y83yy3e
29292.2982
282823
CSV File begin
--------------
ip,time,release

Comment: I included "<" but it didnt worked.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect to your updated question

Answer (score 0):

Using sed :

```
  sed -E -n  '/^-{14}/{n;p;}' file > newfile
```

Using AWK :

```
  awk '/^--------------/{p=1;next}p' file > newfile
```